# Redistricting -- distributing a certain percentage of democrats or republicans into same-size bins

Tags: probability-distributions, applications

Suppose a population of n% Democrats and (100-n)% Republicans was randomly distributed into 10 equally sized districts. Suppose also that n is greater than 50.

What is the most likely outcome?

Is it that about n% of the 10 districts will have a majority of Democratic voters?

Or, is it that each district will most likely have a majority of Democratic voters, resulting in 10 Democratic leaning districts?

Or, is it a 3rd possibility?

Also, does anyone have a quick way to write a Monte-Carlo simulation for this in Python, say?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on the size of the population. If the population is $10$, so one district per person, then $n / 100$ of the districts will have a ($1-0$) majority of Democrats. If the population is large enough, it is nearly certain that all $10$ districts will have a majority of Democrats, even if $n$ is only slightly more than $50$.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the size of the population. If the population is $10$---so, one district per person, then the fraction of Democratic-majority districts is exactly the fraction of Democrats.

If Democrats account for the proportion $p$ of the population $m$, then the proportion of Democrats in any given district has
$$\textrm{mean }p \qquad \textrm{ and} \qquad \textrm{standard deviation }O(m^{-1 / 2}). $$ So, if $p > \frac{1}{2}$, then as $m \to \infty$ the probability that any given district has a Democratic majority approaches $1$, and thus so does the probability that all $10$ districts have a Democratic majority, too.